# LED ceiling fixture certain diodes blinking

Tags: led

My ceiling fixture has all of a sudden stopped working properly. Half the diodes are dark and the others are blinking. Oddly, the same exact ones on each strip work and don't work. I have included a picture to show which ones are blinking and which ones don't work. I am wondering if it is something that I can fix? Maybe replace that driver? And if so, is there a good guide online to walk me through that process? Thanks in advance.
[image: Blinking lights]

Comment: The driver module says "Dimmable driver, 500ma output, 42-48V DC."  This is a constant-current driver (500ma being spec current), presumably that lowers if it is dimmed. The three LED sections look wired in parallel, but I've never heard of 7 LEDs wanting 42-48V (6.0-6.8V per LED, that is *exactly* twice what I'd expect for white LEDs, perhaps each emitter is a double LED in series).

Answer (score 1):

> **I am wondering if it is something that I can fix?**

See [fixing a strobing LED driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UerFD3AgJHE) ;-)

> **Maybe replace that driver?**

That will be easier. The main characteristics are a close match to the the constant-current rating - 500 mA and a voltage range that wholly encompasses the voltage range - 42 to 48 volts.

Before doing that, you can carefully measure the voltage across each of the LEDs or disconnect the LED panels from the fixture and test the LEDs individually in situ.